# Removing shadow from single subview in UIView with shadow

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, shadow

**Context:**
In order to get a shadow on all my tableview cells I have added a shadow to my transparent table view. This to avoid shadows from separate cells falling onto other cells. However, this also means everything in the table view gets a shadow. As I want to have a shadowless remove button appear without shadow when the cell is swiped to the right, I was wondering:

**Question:**
Can I eliminate the shadow from one specific subview in a UIView with a shadow?
Specifically without having to take it out of the table view in this case. I like to keep it in the tableview so that it scrolls with the table view.

Adding shadow to tableView

```
 self.tableView.clipsToBounds         = false
 self.tableView.layer.shadowOffset    = CGSizeMake(5,5)
 self.tableView.layer.shadowColor     = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
 self.tableView.layer.shadowRadius    = 5
 self.tableView.layer.shadowOpacity   = 1
```

and then when the cell is swiped away I simply add the button

```
 let cellFrame = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
 var buttonFrame = CGRectInset(cellFrame,10,8)
 buttonFrame.size.width = 150
 let buttonView = UIButton(frame: buttonFrame)
 buttonView.setTitle("Remove", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
 buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
 tableView.insertSubview(buttonView, atIndex: 0)
 //some animation to move the cell out of the way
```